# Why ethereum not support wallet notify?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/" testnet and api "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/apis" with PHP. But problem is that when someone give me a ether, i am not getting payment receiving ping, is there anything that i can use to have notification whenever i receive payment on my address.

Comment: have you found any solution to solve this?